# Dúvida com parâmetro em Java 8 para gerar números aleatórios usando Collectors.toList()

Tags: java, java-8

Tenho esse método para gerar números aleatórios numa `ArrayList`;

```
public static List<Integer> gerarAleatorio() {

        List<Integer> aleatorios = new ArrayList<>();

        while(aleatorios.size() < 6) {

            int num = (int) (1  + Math.random() * 60);

            if(!aleatorios.contains(num)) {
                aleatorios.add(num);
            }

        }
        return aleatorios;
    }
```

A minha dúvida é porque eu não consigo fazer assim esse método:

```
public static void gerarAleatorio(List<Integer> lista) {
lista = aleatorios.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

e receber a lista aleatório no final, com o `Collectors`.

Comment: O segundo código está incompleto. Tente completá-lo para que a resposta possa ser adequada.

Comment: Ele dá algum erro de compilação dizendo que `aleatorios` não foi declarado no seu segundo método? Além disso, onde é que o seu segundo método chama o `Math.random()`?

Answer (score 3):

Tente fazer assim:

```
private static int gerarNumeroAleatorio() {
    return (int) (1 + Math.random() * 60);
}

public static List<Integer> gerarAleatorio() {
    return Stream.generate(EstaClasse::gerarNumeroAleatorio)
        .distinct()
        .limit(6)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Explicação:

O método `gerarNumeroAleatorio()` é autoexplicativo.

Já o método `gerarAleatorio()`, começa com...

- ... uma sequência infinita de elementos providos pelo método `gerarNumeroAleatorio()`, ...
- ... porém sem repetir elementos, ...
- ... limitado a apenas 6 elementos (e portanto deixando de ser infinita) e ...
- ... colete o resultado disso transformando-o em uma lista.